# T SQL After Update Trigger on column get the value changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I've only started exploring with triggers recently.  I've set up my database mail function and all is working well.  My trigger works perfectly if the column value is changed, but how do I get the value/row that changed?

```
USE [database]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[triggerName] ON [dbo].[tableName]
FOR UPDATE
AS

declare @cust varchar(100);


    if update(Column)
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
        set @cust = THE VALUE MUST GO HERE I ASSUME
    END
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @recipients = 'someone@example.com', 
    @profile_name = 'ProfileName',
    @subject = 'Customer Information Changed', 
    @body = @cust;
```

Comment: In SQL Server, there isn't a "the value" to consider - triggers fire once per *statement*, not once per *row*, and so you may have *multiple* values that have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the values in `inserted` and `deleted`.  If they are not the same, then the value changed.